# Trying to decode the weight from a scale in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hex, scale

I am reading the ble output from a scale and for the life of me I cannot find the weight output.

I am expecting **22.2 kg**

The outputs are:

*[46, 162, 25, 97, 145, 160, 160, 44, 246, 24, 13, 167]*
and/or
*[2E,A2,19,61,91,A0,A0,2C,F6,18,0D,A7]*

I have also tested in **st** and **lb** but again I cannot appear to match up the data. I have tried tweaking this that I have read on other answers which are similar in question but not the same.

```
void main() {
  List<int> received = [[46, 162, 25, 97, 145, 160, 160, 44, 246, 24, 13, 167];
  // Get the weight value from the list starting at index 1
  print(getWeight(received, 1));
}

double getWeight(List<int> data, index) {
  return (( 0xff & data[index + 1] ) << 8 | ( 0xff & data[index] ) << 0 ) / 100;
}
```

and tried from different starting values.

Is there anyone out there that may understand where the weight is at all?

As another example, this should have **24.1 kg**

```
[2E,A2,19,61,91,A0,20,2C,FE,A6,0D,BD]


I/flutter (17484): ScanResult{device: BluetoothDevice{remoteId: A0:91:61:19:A2:2E, localName: AAA002, type: BluetoothDeviceType.le, isDiscoveringServices: false, services: null}, advertisementData: AdvertisementData{localName: AAA002, txPowerLevel: null, connectable: false, manufacturerData: {41132: [46, 162, 25, 97, 145, 160, 32, 44, 254, 166, 13, 189]}, serviceData: {}, serviceUuids: [0000ffb0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]}, rssi: -65, timeStamp: 2023-07-31 13:52:37.268116connectionState: BluetoothConnectionState.disconnected}
```

Also, this one in lb should be **58.4**
46, 162, 25, 97, 145, 160, 160, 160, 160, 163, 6, 137

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: most likely you need https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html